# Check if current controller has parent of some other controller inside the application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I have a separete part of the site for separate, dedicated customers, they have tools under /dedicated path, and all controllers they have are inheritences of DedicatedController.
I want to create a before_filter in application_controller to protect this customers from opening any other pages that are not in controllers that inherited by dedicated_controlle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `before_filter` in the ApplicationController to prevent customers from going to pages there you can use `skip_filter` in the base controller for the DedicatedController.

So for ours we have:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_not_a_customer
  .
  .
end
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  skip_filter :ensure_not_a_customer
  .
  .
end
class Admin::WebpageController < Admin::BaseController
  .
  .
end
```

Then anything inherited from Admin::BaseController will skip the before_filter from the ApplicationController.